# How convert an mbox to a JSON structure?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to convert an mbox to a JSON structure suitable for import into MongoDB i.e.
I am using mining social web second edition mailbox chapter but its not working properly.
I am trying to convert an mbox to a JSON structure suitable for import into MongoDB i.e.
I am using mining social web second edition mailbox chapter but its not working properly.

```
 import sys
 import mailbox
 import email
 import quopri
 import json
 import time
 from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
 from dateutil.parser import parse

 MBOX = 'resources/ch06-mailboxes/data/enron.mbox'
 OUT_FILE = MBOX + '.json'

 def cleanContent(msg):

 # Decode message from "quoted printable" format, but first
 # re-encode, since decodestring will try to do a decode of its own
 msg = quopri.decodestring(msg.encode('utf-8'))

 # Strip out HTML tags, if any are present.
 # Bail on unknown encodings if errors happen in BeautifulSoup.
 try:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(msg)
 except:
    return ''
 return ''.join(soup.findAll(text=True))

  # There's a lot of data to process, and the Pythonic way to do it is with a 
  # generator. See http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators.
  # Using a generator requires a trivial encoder to be passed to json for object 
  # serialization.

 class Encoder(json.JSONEncoder):
 def default(self, o): return  list(o)
 # The generator itself...
 def gen_json_msgs(mb):
    while 1:
    msg = mb.next()
    if msg is None:
        break

    yield jsonifyMessage(msg)

  def jsonifyMessage(msg):
  json_msg = {'parts': []}
  for (k, v) in msg.items():
    json_msg[k] = v.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')

  # The To, Cc, and Bcc fields, if present, could have multiple items.
  # Note that not all of these fields are necessarily defined.

  for k in ['To', 'Cc', 'Bcc']:
    if not json_msg.get(k):
        continue
    json_msg[k] = json_msg[k].replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '').replace('\r', '')\
                             .replace(' ', '').decode('utf-8', 'ignore').split(',')

  for part in msg.walk():
     json_part = {}

    if part.get_content_maintype() != 'text':
        print >> sys.stderr, "Skipping MIME content in JSONification        
    ({0})".format(part.get_content_maintype())
        continue

    json_part['contentType'] = part.get_content_type()
    content = part.get_payload(decode=False).decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
    json_part['content'] = cleanContent(content)
    json_msg['parts'].append(json_part)

# Finally, convert date from asctime to milliseconds since epoch using the
# $date descriptor so it imports "natively" as an ISODate object in MongoDB
then = parse(json_msg['Date'])
millis = int(time.mktime(then.timetuple())*1000 + then.microsecond/1000)
json_msg['Date'] = {'$date' : millis}

return json_msg

mbox = mailbox.UnixMailbox(open(MBOX, 'rb'), email.message_from_file)

# Write each message out as a JSON object on a separate line
# for easy import into MongoDB via mongoimport

f = open(OUT_FILE, 'w')
for msg in gen_json_msgs(mbox):
 if msg != None:
    f.write(json.dumps(msg, cls=Encoder) + '\n')
f.close()

print "All done"

getting error:
80 # for easy import into MongoDB via mongoimport
  81 
  ---> 82 f = open(OUT_FILE, 'w')
  83 for msg in gen_json_msgs(mbox):
  84     if msg != None:

IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'resources/ch06-mailboxes/data/enron.mbox.json'
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you mentioned became obsolete in [Third Edition of Mining Social Web](https://github.com/mikhailklassen/Mining-the-Social-Web-3rd-Edition)

I tried making a workable script that not just converts MBOX to JSON, but even extracts the Attachments to usable formats.
Link to the repo -
https://github.com/PS1607/mbox-to-json

Read the [README](https://github.com/PS1607/mbox-to-json/blob/main/README.md) file for usage instructions.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33634159)

Comment: I maintain that repo(link). It won't change/delete.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your problem is related to user permissions instead of Python. Line 82 tries to open a file in the "data" folder, but permission was denied. You should try executing your script using the `sudo` command from a terminal:

```
sudo python3 <your script name>
```

This should take care of the error you pointed out.

PS: Python 3 uses `print` as a function; line 88 should read

```
print('All done')
```

Comment: Maybe you could demonstrate how to use it?